# failing to use a pointer to a function as member of a class

Tags: c++

i have the following problem:
i have a pointer to a function as a member of class B which exists in an encapsulating class A.

```
Class A
{
public:
ObjAbs*  CreateObject(int id);

private:
 Class B
 {
   typedef ObjAbs* (B::*pfnObjAlloc)();
   pfnObjAlloc mfnAlloc;
   MemPool* mpPool;

   template<typename T>
    ObjAbs* TAlloc()
    {
            ObjAbs* pObj = NULL;
            void *memory = NULL;

            if(mpMemPool)
                memory = mpMemPool->Alloc();

            if (NULL != memory)
                param = new (memory) T();

            return ObjAbs;
        }

 }

B mAllocArr[maxObjsId];

    A::A()
    {
       mAlloArr[id1] = &A::B::TAlloc<Obj1>;
       mAlloArr[id2] = &A::B::TAlloc<Obj2>;
       .
       .
       .
    }

}
```

I am trying to access it from class A in the following manner:

```
ObjAbs*  A::CreateObject(int id)
{
  ObjAbs* pObj = NULL;
  if(NULL != AllocArr[id].mfnAlloc)
    pObj = (AllocArr[id].*mfnAlloc)(); <-- There lies the problem

  return pObj;
}
```

i keep getting the following error:
error C2065: 'mfnAlloc' : undeclared identifier

Can someone help me?

Thanks,

Comment: start with adding `A::` before `CreateObject(int id)` definition

Comment: you're sure the error doesn't pop up one line above ?

Comment: the A:: is in the code. i forgot to add it. thanks. the error according to the compiler is in the line i marked.

Comment: when i left only the if statement and added dummy code instead of the problematic one, there was no compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

```
pObj = (AllocArr[id].*mfnAlloc)();
```

tries to look up `mfnAlloc` in the current scope, not in `B`'s.

The syntax for calling a pointer-to-member-function is `(object.*function)()`, and since both `object` and `function` are evaluated in the current scope, you need something more like

```
(AllocArr[id].*(AllocArr[id].mfnAlloc))();
```

which is a hideous mess  of code, so it's probably a better idea to add another member function to `B`:

```
ObjAbs* allocate()
{
    return (*mfnAlloc)();
}
```

so you can write the more readable

```
pObj = AllocArr[id].allocate();
```